# Get status of autossh tunnel

Tags: linux, ssh, tunnel

I created a an ssh tunnel using autossh using `autossh -M 0 -o "ServerAliveInterval 30" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" -fN -T -R 22222:localhost:22 console@<server_ip>`. It worked fine for a while but now appears closed. How can I check whether the tunnel is open?

I tried:

`lsof -i -n | egrep '\<ssh\>' | grep <server_ip>`

This returned:

`ssh     28517   username    3u  IPv4 4649313      0t0  TCP 192.168.13.100:37096-><server_ip>:ssh (ESTABLISHED)`

I thought that response should indicate that the tunnel is open (I would expect return=1 if no tunnel), but when I try to use the tunnel I get:

`ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused`

What do I need to use to check the status of the tunnel from the client?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like someone gave a pretty thorough answer on Stack Exchange [using a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998297/ssh-check-if-a-tunnel-is-alive).

Comment: I had looked at that question but I thought it wasn't applicable because the OP was using -L instead of -R. In the accepted answer I missed that netstat was being run on the server, not the client. I've got it applied now.

Answer (score 1):

You can check on remote side with

```bash
watch -n 0.5 "netstat -tulpn"
```